# Once a wide variety of spammers have an email address is there any way to recover it without using aggressive spam filtering

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

When I first set up my email address I got very little spam. I am not a fan of spam filtering in general and I prefer to manually check the spam; however I made some mistakes over the years including using my email for domain registration which made it visible on the web .... and of course now I get a huge amount of spam daily so I need to do something.

I would prefer to avoid using spam filtering, or at least set the filters in favor of no false positives but I doubt this would make the account usable.

**My question** ... is there any way to recover this email without using very tight spam filtering or would I be better off just getting a new email account? I guess what I'm in effect asking is whether or not emails get deleted from spammers lists over time or whether given that they now have it the best I can do is fight it with aggressive filtering

Comment: This question is very much subjective to opinion. One will argue that you should get a new email address, while another argues that you can try and setup anti-spam methods. In the end, spamming will always be there and no matter what you do, if you use your email address on the internet, sooner or later it will attract spammers. Also, lots and lots of spam can mean a spyware infection.

Comment: I think few email addresses would ever be removed from spammers lists. Such lists are sold with huge numbers of addresses and the seller has little concern over invalid addresses. These lists often contain millions of addresses and I am sure large numbers haven't been used for years. SPAM is a volume business. The costs of determining which addresses are invalid far outweigh the benefits.

Comment: @LMiller7 thanks that's what I'm beginning to think I just never heard anyone else say it ... if you put this as an answer I'll give it the tick unless someone has evidence to the contrary

Comment: @LPChip yes I know what you're saying and sorry I didn't mean to sway the question so far into an either-or position - what I MEANT to ask was whether there was any reasonable possibility or not of recovering the email without using automatic spam software. The spam has built up over many years of my address being visible I think --- thanks

Comment: @LPChip it begs the question doesn't it of whether all email addresses have an effective lifetime due to the fact that it's hard to keep addresses completely off of spammers lists ... if indeed it's true that "if they have it then they have it"

Comment: This is a Q and A site, which means we're trying to provide an answer based on facts to limit it down to just one answer. That does make it an either, or case, and makes this question highly subjective to opinion based answers, which is considered Off-topic here on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think few email addresses would ever be removed from spammers lists. Such lists are sold with huge numbers of addresses and the seller has little concern over invalid addresses. These lists often contain millions of addresses and I am sure large numbers haven't been used for years. SPAM is a volume business. It is all about the few who respond, not the large majority that do not. The costs of determining which addresses are invalid far outweigh the benefits.